# Were the events of the Evil Dead movies cancelled out by the events of Ash vs Evil Dead?

Tags: plot-explanation, evil-dead, ash-vs-evil-dead

In *Ash vs Evil Dead*, the protagonist

> destroys the cabin when they travel back in time.

I understand that this nullifies what happens in the previous movies.

Is my understanding of these events correct?

Comment: Just to clarify: are you asking whether the events of the original movies no longer happened as of *Ash vs Evil Dead*?

Comment: maybe "cancelled" was not the correct word to use, but yes i mean that

Comment: I've edited the question to try and clarify that, let me know if I've accidentally made any changes you're not happy with.

Comment: I'm reading a lot of contradictory things about the timelines of the series, as I guess there were constantly rights issues from one series or film to another. I also don't know how accurate the following is, but I found someone who claimed to make a "definitive" timeline (or shows the iterations of timelines): http://evildeadarmyofdarkness.blogspot.com/p/thevil-dead-definitive-timeline.html

Comment: I don't get the downvotes, it looks like a legit question

Comment: Maybe the downvotes were from before F1Krazy's edits.  It's a lot easier to understand the question now.